# Full screen image view on tap via UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, fullscreen, gestures

I have a JSON UICollectionView section of my app. My original idea for the code has changed and now I simply want the image selected to appear full screen as a 'lightbox' styled effect with full zoom gesture control.

I'm having trouble getting any code to work either through gestures or other methods for my Collection View.

Here is a snippet of the view generation:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView       numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myObject.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CustomColumnCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:path]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    myCell.displayImage.image = img;
    myCell.displayDetail.text= [tmpDict objectForKey:name];

    return myCell;
}
```

How do I simply enable a full screen view of the image tapped? I can get it in a new view controller but all I simply need is a 'lightbox' style effect where the image animates towards the main screen and fills it in it's aspect ratio?

The code below shows part of how I'm able to click on the items to generate a simple view controller. But I need it on the same screen, simply over-layed in full screen:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *IndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setImageItem:[tmpDict objectForKey:path]];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:[tmpDict objectForKey:name]];

    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this library its very helpful and easy to implement
https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you want to browse selected image with animation you can use [JTSImageViewController](https://github.com/mash/JTSImageViewController)

Add library classes and do this code thats it.

```
    // Create image info
    JTSImageInfo *imageInfo = [[JTSImageInfo alloc] init];
    imageInfo.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.attachments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"attach_file"]];
    imageInfo.referenceRect = self.frame;
    imageInfo.referenceView = self.superview;

    // Setup view controller
    JTSImageViewController *imageViewer = [[JTSImageViewController alloc]
                                           initWithImageInfo:imageInfo
                                           mode:JTSImageViewControllerMode_Image
                                           backgroundStyle:JTSImageViewControllerBackgroundOption_Blurred];

    // Present the view controller.
    [imageViewer showFromViewController:self transition:JTSImageViewControllerTransition_FromOriginalPosition];
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks but how do I connect them together?

Comment: You can add gesture on UIImageView and on click of that imageview you can write this code. but this code required called from viewcontroller so i suggest you to make one delegate method and call that with this code.